# Difference between Delphi 2007 and 2010 when drawing on bitmaps

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010, delphi-2007, transparent, tbitmap

The following code works as expected with Delphi 2007. It takes a bitmap from an image list, draws a red X over it, and adds the new bitmap to the end of the same image list:

```
  DynBmp:=Graphics.TBitMap.Create;
  DynBmp.Transparent:=TRUE;
  DynBmp.TransparentMode:=tmFixed;
  ImgList.GetBitmap(9, DynBmp);
  DynBmp.TransparentColor:=DynBmp.canvas.pixels[0, DynBmp.Height - 1];
  DynBmp.Canvas.MoveTo(1, 1);
  DynBmp.Canvas.Pen.Style:=psAlternate; //psSolid;
  DynBmp.Canvas.Pen.Color:=clRed;
  DynBmp.Canvas.Pen.Width:=2;
  DynBmp.Canvas.LineTo(DynBmp.Width - 1, DynBmp.Height - 1);
  DynBmp.Canvas.MoveTo(DynBmp.Width - 1, 1);
  DynBmp.Canvas.LineTo(1, DynBmp.Height - 1);
  FErrBmpIdx:=ImgList.AddMasked(DynBmp, DynBmp.TransParentColor);
  aResetIcon.ImageIndex:=FErrBmpIdx;
  FreeAndNil(DynBmp);
```

On Delphi 2010, using the same code, the red X becomes a transparent X. What do I need to add/change to get it working as expected with Delphi 2010? Thanks

Comment: I tried this on 2010, and it worked like expected.

Comment: The cause appears to be the conversion of the bitmap (it is originally a PNG resource, which is converted into a bitmap before this drawing stage). I'm not sure how the conversion is causing it, but we've fixed it simply by having this resource as a bitmap instead of a PNG.

Answer (score 2):

I had faced the same problem with Delphi XE2 and had fixed it by unchecking the "**Use XP style image with alpha channel**" option in ImageList Editor. If you had checked that option just uncheck it.

Answer (score 0):

DynBmp.TransParentColor is probably clRed before you add it to the imagelist again. Maybe TransparentMode is not tmFixed anymore? Try debugging and fix your code according to your findings.

Comment: The transparent color is not red (and besides, the graphic is identical to the one in D2007). The comment about tmFixed makes no sense as I am setting the transparent color (see .TransparentColor).

Comment: Also, the bitmap is wrong before it is added to the list (so the problem is not with adding it to the list).

Comment: I don't have Delphi 2010, so I can't debug for you. But have you concluded TransParentColor is not clRed and TransparentMode is tmFixed before you add it to the imagelist by debugging or by reasoning?

Comment: The pixel that is actually used for transparency may or may not be `Pixels[0, DynBmp.Height - 1]`, depending on whether the bitmap is set to bottom-up or top-down. Your code is assuming the bitmap will always be bottom-up.

Comment: Also, if the bitmap you pass to `AddMasked()` does not have the same `PixelFormat` as the `TImageList`, then `AddMasked()` will create a temporary bitmap internally, and that may lose the transparency info.  So make sure you set your bitmap's `PixelFormat` before calling `GetBitmap()`.